# Draw Hasse undestand how to do it

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have been reading diagram Hasse.My question is how i give position to numbers on diagram.Let me explain
Example 1 :Lets say i have a set A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
i will draw with the smallest part 1 and this will have 2 3 5 and 7.From up the 2 it will be have 4 and 8.Up to 3 it will have the 6.In 5 and 7 nothing.

Example 2:Lets say i have A={12,18,22,23,25,29,32,40} . I did this because on my exercise are simple.How can it be something like this?How i position the numbers?What i will do is starting point 12.Can it be something like this ?
Could you explain me how i position the numbers because i am getting confused.Thanks

Comment: You need a binary relation on the set $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two small examples:  $A=\{1,2,3\}$ with partial order $R=\{(2,1),(2,3)\}$

Our Hasse Diagram will look like this:

$\begin{array}{ccc}1&&3\\ \backslash & & /\\&2\end{array}$

To craft the diagram, we not only need to know what the set is, but we also need to know what the order is.  In this example $(2,1)\in R$ so $2$ should appear "below" $1$.  Similarly $(2,3)\in R$ so $2$ should appear below $3$.  $1$ and $3$ are not related however, so they should not have any lines comparing them.  Note also, despite $1$ being the "smaller number" according to our *usual* description, that is irrelevant here.

---

Let $B=\{00,01,10,11\}$ with order $S=\{(00,01),(00,10),(00,11),(01,11),(10,11)\}$

Here we have our Hasse diagram like this:

$\begin{array}{ccc}&11\\/&&\backslash\\01&&10\\\backslash&&/\\&00\end{array}$

Note that in this example that although $00$ is below $11$, we don't bother drawing a line directly between them, this is taken care of by the fact that there are longer paths leading only upwards that you can take instead.  Further, notice that both $01$ and $10$ are below $11$.

---

See more examples and more details in your textbook or on [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).

As for your specific example you ask about, there is not enough information to begin constructing the diagram as it requires knowledge of what the order to be used is.